# Make field of submodel unique in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make the name of a submodel unique but I can't think of a way to do it. Imagine I have the following model architecture:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
   name = field.CharField(...)
   class Meta:
      abstract = False

class Panther(Animal):
   class Meta:
     ...

class Tiger(Animal):
   class Meta:
    ....
```

Now, what I want is that within the scope of the subclasses, the name of should be unique. So let's say I have a Tiger called JackTheTiger and a Panther called JackyThePanther, then no other Tiger with this name should allowed to be created and no other Panther with the name JackyThePanther should be allowed to be created.

But I want to be able to create a Tiger which is called JackyThePanther and a panther which is also called JackyThePanther. So the uniqueness should only be applied within the scope of the submodel.

I tried 2 ways to achieve what I want, both are not optimal:

1. I create a name field for each submodel and make it unique. But then I can't query all animals and serialize the name. It also seems like bad architecture to me
2. I make Animal abstract. But this is no option for me since I need the database table for animal
   (3. I also thought about a custom validator but I don't think it's possible because I could only validate the instances of the Supermodel)

Is there another way to achieve what I intend? Help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its your solution

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        (1, 'Tyger'),
        (2, 'Panter')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    type_of_animal = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['name','type_of_animal']]
```

In this case you can create JackyThePanther for 'Tyger' and 'Panter'. You can expand logic, for example add 'Elephant' JackyThePanther

```
>>> animals = Animal.objects.all()
>>> animals = Animal.objects.filter(name='JackyThePanther')
>>> animals
<QuerySet [<Animal: Animal object (1)>, <Animal: Animal object (2)>]>
```

Comment: That works indeed perfectly! Only downside is I have to add an extra field. But I can keep the inheritance and it validates the uniqueness. Perfect, thank you, appreciated very much (upvoted your question, but have not enough rep)

Comment: It is your decision, but my opinion is: better create one extra field than extra model, you can validate uniqueness as you want(if I understood correctly): if you add JackTheTiger as Tiger, you will be able to add JackyThePanther as Panter or JackyThePanther as Tiger, and also JackyTheTiger as  Panter. But after you added  JackTheTiger as Tiger you will not be able to add any Tiger with name JackTheTiger.

Comment: yes you are right. I ended up rethinking my setup. I implemented a single model `Animal` without any subclasses but with the field `type_animal`. Then I added your solution to the single model and this results in a way less complex setup.

Answer (score 1):

Model inheritance in Django is rarely the best solution, and I don't think I'd turn to it in your case. You're already seeing the pitfalls it can come with in situations that aren't perfectly suited to it.

[`Meta.unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) is a model option that enables what you seem to be looking for, though you'll have to change the approach you're using:

```
class Species(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(...)

class Animal(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(...)
   species = models.ForeignKey(Species, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
   class Meta:
      unique_together = [['name', 'species']]
```

In this case, you'd likely maintain a [data migration or fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/) for species, as your current architecture has them predefined in code.

*Note that this uses `unique_together`, which is currently valid, but the linked documentation mentions that [`UniqueConstrant`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) is likely more future-proof. I'm sticking with the former as a demonstration here since it's the one I've used.*

Comment: Thank you @kungphu, that looks like what I need. Unfortunately I can not change the model inheritance. I need a common Superclass to point other model FKs to my `Animal-Superclass` (upvoted your question but have not enough rep)

Comment: I rethought my model setup and also with your suggestion that `model inheritance in Django is rarely the best solution` I got rid of the inheritance, as commented above. I wonder though why django in general doesn't fit well with inheritance. I guess the challenges are somewhere on the line of OOP and DB-architecture?

Comment: @shadow Inheritance in general is a bit oversold. It's a great tool, but its complexity cost increases drastically as your classes gain functionality; in this case, it's in no small part due to Django models being tied to its ORM. Which, in the general case, is excellent. But when you add inheritance to that, you end up having to be very careful about what you expect, and hope to your favorite deity you've considered all the ways your models might be used _and_ changed down the road. Since that's basically impossible, it's something to be very, very careful with.